# Sharepoint 2013 JSLink (CSR) Not Working

Tags: sharepoint, rendering, client-side, jslink

I'm trying to make our list view as an accordion by following this tutorial:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-ccdb2a0e

-

I followed the tutorial:

Create a Custom List, add a new column to the list:

Name: Description

Type: Multiple lines of text

Edit the Default New Form

Go to List view web-part properties and add the JSLink file (~sitecollection/Style Library/JSLink-Samples/Accordion.js) to JS link property under the Miscellaneous Tab. Click Apply.

-

Nothing changed, so I added a Script Editor in that page and pasted js code. Then it kind of works.

Is there anything I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the list view is rendered properly when `Description` field is type of `Plain text` from the specified example.

To render it properly when `Description` field is type of `Rich text` or `Enhanced`, replace the `accordionTemplate` function with this one:

```
function accordionTemplate(ctx) { 
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"]; 
    var description = ctx.CurrentItem["Description"]; 

    // construct List Item  
    return "<h2>" + title + "</h2><p>" + $(description).html() + "</p><br/>"; 
}
```

Result

[image]

---

I would recommend you to try another approach to render List View as accordion as demonstrated in [Customize the rendering of a List View in Sharepoint 2013: Displaying List Items in Accordion](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/14/customize-the-rendering-of-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-2013-displaying-list-items-in-accordion/) article.

Key points:

- [jQuery IU Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) is used for rendering List Items as collapsible
  content panels
- demonstrates how to load multiple JavaScript libraries (e.g. jQuery)
  using `JSLink` property

Result

[image]